# Avoid masked array elements being formatted as '0.00'

Tags: numpy, formatting, masked-array

I have a masked array in numpy:

```
masked = np.ma.core.MaskedArray([1, 2], mask=[True, False])
```

Now I want to display the numbers in a plot, so I need formatting:

```
"{:.2f}".format(masked[0])
'0.00'
"{:.2f}".format(masked[1])
'2.00'
```

Why is a masked element formatted as '0.00' and how can I avoid this, e.g. by formatting the masked element to NaN or some arbitrary character?

Comment: But why would you have to format it? You can display masked data in a `matplotlib` plot simply with `plt.plot(x,masked)`.

Comment: Use `masked.filled(fill_value)` to replace the masked value(s) with the desired fill value.  Beware, though, that you have an integer dtype array, so you can only fill it with integers, not strings or `nan` (a float).

Comment: Oh, perfect, @hpaulj that did the job! You may post thi as an answer if you like!
@ Ardweaden: It was a bit more complicated, I did an annotated heat map with plt.imshow, and the text is actually coming from that array I introduced in the question.